# Oracle Query Speed Comparison

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose that I have a table in two different situation.

1. One with about 3,000,000 records which I should perform a calculation after each query which may take about 2 or 3 seconds.
2. In other situation I have about 300,000,000 records in the table and no post calculation is required after each query.

I want to compare total time required for each process. Suppose that both tables are indexed and partitioned in same way and Oracle DBMS is used in both situations.

Comment: So run some benchmarks and do a comparison. Are you expecting us to do it for you?

Comment: I want to know if some one has same experience, share it with me. Also this is a general question for who is expert in working with oracle DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the end result the same? e.g. table which is 10 * bigger = the result of t1 & calculation?

You could set up a test to run through a decent sample size and just

```
 set timing on;
```

to compare the results. There isn't really a hard and fast rule about this - just be sure to consider all parts of the database / setup (e.g. if this is interacts with a webapp then test via the app rather than plain sqlplus - although this shouldn't make much difference).

The following article has some good points about a good test case:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7413988573867